# Python sort strings with dot/separated numbers and strings at the end

Tags: python, sorting

I have an array of dicts like:

`array_x = 
[{'title': 'Copy -- @1.1 true files'}, {'title': 'Copy -- @1.11 true files'}, {'title': 'Copy -- @1.3 true files'}, {'title': 'Copy -- @1.2 true files'}, {'title': 'Copy -- @1.12 true files'}, {'title': 'Copy -- @1.22 true files'}, {'title': 'After -- @1.1 copy files'}]`

I want to sort them by the key 'title', i try to use the comun sort function and some like this:

`array_x.sort(key=lambda s: list(map(str, s['title'].split('.'))))`

but doesn't work, i want some like this:

`[{'title': 'After -- @1.1 copy files'}, {'title': 'Copy -- @1.1 true files'}, {'title': 'Copy -- @1.2 true files'}, {'title': 'Copy -- @1.3 true files'}, {'title': 'Copy -- @1.11 true files'}, {'title': 'Copy -- @1.12 true files'}, {'title': 'Copy -- @1.22 true files'}]`

I'm using Python 3.6.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this: discard everything before and including the `@` sign, then convert each period-separated section into ints. That should fix the problem of the digit sequences being sorted lexicographically.

```
>>> array_x = [{'title': 'Copy -- @1.1'}, {'title': 'Copy -- @1.11'}, {'title': 'Copy -- @1.3'}, {'title': 'Copy -- @1.2'}, {'title': 'Copy -- @1.12'}, {'title': 'Copy -- @1.22'}, {'title': 'After -- @1.1'}]
>>> array_x.sort(key=lambda s: list(map(int, s['title'].rpartition("@")[2].split('.'))))
>>> array_x
[{'title': 'After -- @1.1'}, {'title': 'Copy -- @1.1'}, {'title': 'Copy -- @1.2'}, {'title': 'Copy -- @1.3'}, {'title': 'Copy -- @1.11'}, {'title': 'Copy -- @1.12'}, {'title': 'Copy -- @1.22'}]
```

---

Edit: if you can't guarantee that the string ends with digit sequences, then instead of rpartition, try using `re.findall` to extract the digits from anywhere in the string:

```
>>> import re
>>> array_x = [{'title': 'Copy -- @1.1 copy file'}, {'title': 'Copy -- @1.11 true files'}, {'title': 'Copy -- @1.3 true files'}, {'title': 'Copy -- @1.2'}, {'title': 'Copy -- @1.12'}, {'title': 'Copy -- @1.22'}, {'title': 'After -- @1.1'}]
>>> array_x.sort(key=lambda s: list(map(int, re.findall(r"\d+", s['title']))))
>>> array_x
[{'title': 'Copy -- @1.1 copy file'}, {'title': 'After -- @1.1'}, {'title': 'Copy -- @1.2'}, {'title': 'Copy -- @1.3 true files'}, {'title': 'Copy -- @1.11 true files'}, {'title': 'Copy -- @1.12'}, {'title': 'Copy -- @1.22'}]
```

---

Edit part 2: if you want to break ties based on the textual content of the title, put it in a tuple with the numeric list content:

```
>>> array_x.sort(key=lambda s: (list(map(int, re.findall(r"\d+", s['title']))), s['title']))
>>> array_x
[{'title': 'After -- @1.1'}, {'title': 'Copy -- @1.1 copy file'}, {'title': 'Copy -- @1.2'}, {'title': 'Copy -- @1.3 true files'}, {'title': 'Copy -- @1.11 true files'}, {'title': 'Copy -- @1.12'}, {'title': 'Copy -- @1.22'}]
```

Comment: Its close!! But i need sort them by the first word string and number, cuz i have a loot of different first word, i need some like:

`[{'title': 'After -- @1.1 copy'}, {'title': 'Before -- @1.1 move'}, {'title': 'Before -- @1.2 move'}, {'title': 'Copy -- @1.1'}, {'title': 'Copy -- @1.2'} ]`


but i think i can separate them, so much tanks!!!